# React get item from local storage after refresh in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning to use functional components in React and I've made a simple thing to increase and decrease numbers. I'm also using local storage, which works fine, but I want that the number would stay the same after refreshing the page. In that case, where would localStorage.getItem go if I want to use it once, when the component loads? As I understand useEffect works everytime when component renders. Can componentDidMount be used in functional components to get item from storage?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './Clicker.css';


function Clicker() {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("number", number)
    })
    function refresh() {
        return localStorage.setItem("number", 0),
        setNumber(0);
    }
  return (
    <div className="clicker">
        <p className="number">{number}</p>
        <button className="add-button" onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}>+</button>
        <button className="refresh-button" onClick={() => refresh()}>0</button>
        <button className="substract-button" onClick={() => setNumber(number - 1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Clicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update localStorage, whenever you increase or decrease the number.
Also when the page is refreshed, the number will be reintialized.

```
function Clicker() {
    const previousNumber = localStorage.getItem("number") || 0;
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(previousNumber);
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("number", number)
    }, [number])
    // then this function is useless
    function refresh() {
        return localStorage.setItem("number", 0),
        setNumber(0);
    }
  return (
    <div className="clicker">
        <p className="number">{number}</p>
        <button className="add-button" onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}>+</button>
        <button className="refresh-button" onClick={() => refresh()}>0</button>
        <button className="substract-button" onClick={() => setNumber(number - 1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am not sure about the code inside the refresh method, it will become useless. You may try to refresh page programmatically.